# An strucure to share data between scopes

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, code-structure

I am just learning JS and try to write a simple game. So I made a basic structure witch should look something like this (pseudo c++ code):

```
if (!game.game_stage)
    game.reset_game(); // initialize game objects
if (player1.score > MAX_SCORE || player2.score > MAX_SCORE)
    game.end_round(); stop(1000);
else
    game.update();
game.render();
```

Then I try to write it in JS:

```
function main() {
    if (gamest != true) {
        resetgame();
        gamest = true;
    }
    /* UPDATE SECTION */
    if (score1 > 9 || score2 > 9) {
        endround();
        setTimeOut(update, 1000);
    }
    else {
        update();
    }
    /* RENDER SECTION */
    draw();
}
```

Other functions in `main()` does now have access to objects initialized in `resetgame()` function. The other problem that appears is that `setTimeOut(update, 1000)` does not work when I put all object to global scope for testing.

`resetgame()` procedure looks pretty much like this:

```
function resetgame() {
    var paddle1 = new GameObject(20, 80, "LEFT");
    [...]
```

Does that structure makes any sens?

Comment: Please show us where you define the variables you have trouble accessing, as it might be a scope issue. Also, please define "does not work" - do you see any error messages in the dev console?

Comment: It's really hard to understand what you're dealing with and what your actual problem is. Your explanations seem a little bit jumpy, like here is a corner  and then a glimpse on another corner and oh sigh, it doesn't work #frownyface. I don't understand what your structure is, not even what your approach (way of mind) to structuring this is, and not what fails. I wrote a little tic-tac-toe game the other day for a different question. It was a pretty quick shot, but it is encapsulated into a class and deals with internal state and methods and maybe the code helps https://jsfiddle.net/pg6xpyjo/1/

Comment: Sorry, I may not be clear. But I did show above that I declare my "game objects" in `resetgame()` function and try to access them in draw() and update(). But then I'm getting "ReferenceError: [x] is not defined". The game I'm writing is a Pong. And for the structure, I first use this cheep if statement: `(gamest != true) {
        resetgame();
        gamest = true;
    }` where all objects get initialized and I will be using variable `gamest` to reset all the values when the game is over.  Later you see I'm checking if the player score is equal to maximum value and changing the round.

Comment: .. Else i simply execute regular game `update()`. Last is the `draw()` witch takes care of rendering all objects to the screen.

Comment: `I declare my "game objects" in resetgame() function and try to access them in draw() and update(). But then I'm getting "ReferenceError: [x] is not defined"` function declarations inside other functions can access the surrounding scope, and all it's variables (that's called a [tag:closure]), but outer functions can not access the scope of some inner or foreign function, except the values that the function actively exposes. That's why you get the ReferenceError. So one (poor) possibility would be to spam the global scope, the other you define some ((semi-)public) state on the game object

Comment: Can u explain me what you mean with "((semi-)public) state"? If I will need to use global scope so it's better to change my structure. And, can you give me some hint why the 'setTimeOut(update, 1000)' function does not stop the 'upate()' for one second? Debuger sends no error about this but after `endround()` executes then program jumps right in to `update()`.

Comment: In JS everything is public. JS simply doesn't know a private or internal namespace. We can simulate privacy, using closures, but it's just a (very common) mock, not exactly the same as a real private namespace, and it has its own disatvantages in terms of performance,memory,... it's a whole world to talk about. So in JS it is common to mark "private" properties with an underscore: `obj._privateProp`. This is just a naming convention, therefore semi-public. These properties are fully public, but they are marked as ["U can't touch this"](http://google.com/search?q=u%20can%27t%20touch%20this) :D

Comment: Boiling down to: "These properties *(starting with an underscore)*, although you can access them, are not part of the public API. And if you mess with them, you may be screwed. Or we may change/remove them in our next update and then you're screwed"

Comment: `And, can you give me some hint why the 'setTimeOut(update, 1000)' function does not stop the 'upate()' for one second?` I'm not entiely sure what you mean by that. If you think of `setTimeout` as a `sleep` in c++, suspending the thread is no option in JS, since it is single-threaded, it will freeze your entire page, everything! setTimeout is more like a "hey dude, call me back in a minute, at this number/function here. I have to do sth. in the meantime"

Comment: Sure, I know what you mean, but what have semi-public modules with scope accessibility to do? And I am using the HTML5 canvas, thats what I want to do, frezze the update(), so player gets a second between rounds. It must not be so hard to just freeze the game for a second ..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### The problem

```
function main() {
    if (gamest != true) {
        resetgame();
        gamest = true;
    }
```

The `resetgame()` function is bound inside an `if` scope. It cause the objects initialized inside this scope to be destroyed after program leaves that scope.

#### Closure solution

To get use of closure concept we need:

- variable
- body of logic that variable is bound to
- environment that is saved during the closure's instantiation, this is for free variables that exist within the body to be bound when the closure variable is evaluated.

So in this example, we would need a bunch of free object inside the `function main()` body to save data evaluated by `resetgame()`. One option will be to pass all those object by arguments to the `resetgame()` and rewrite it to initialize all arguments to its inner objects.

#### Simple OOP solution

In a game we usually have a lot of objects, so the closure concept will get to complex and memory consuming. The better solution will be to encapsulate all main functions in to one object so we can easy exchange data and pass the object where-ever we need. That let us create an easy to menage structure, e.g.:

```
var App = {
    Load: function() {
       this.frame = new Frame();
    },
    // UPDATE
    Update: function() {
       this.frame.updatePosition();
    },
    // RENDER
    Render: function() {
       this.frame.draw();
    }
};

function Main() {
    var app = App;
    app.Load();
    setInterval(MainLoop(app), 1000/60);
}

function MainLoop(app) {
    // main application render
    app.Render();
    // main application update
    app.Update();
}
```

*Someone just remind me about this question. I'm not a JS expert yet but for that application I find my solution. I know that could be solved better but this solution is good enough for the little game I been writing. But if someone have a better one, I will be glad to hear your opinion.*